# How do I tar dot files but not dot directories

Tags: linux, bash, tar

The following tar command will exclude all dot files and dot directories.

```
tar -cvzf /media/bjackfly/bkup/bkup.gz --exclude '.*' --one-file-system /home/bjackfly
```

In my case I want the dot files to be backed up in the home directory (`.vimrc`, `.bashrc`) etc. but not the dot directories `/.config` `/.cache` `/.eclipse` etc.

Any Linux gurus with a command for this, or do I need to run a find into a tar or do two different tar commands which is non-ideal? One for dot files in the home directory and one for everything else?

Comment: Why do you not want the hidden directories? They're part of the user configuration as well.

Comment: Mainly because I don't know how to ghost or restore a linux image. I would like to learn though. In the past I just back up all my data files and dot files like .vimrc etc  and then usually have to go through the pain of reinstalling the OS the apps and all the tools like eclipse etc. which is never fun. If you have some advice on how to restore ubuntu linux as an image that would be great

Comment: [this is a very similar question][1]. the chosen answer is quite elegant and concise.

  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83661/creating-archive-using-tar-including-all-dotfiles-but-excluding-all-subdirecto

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's not relevant to his question.

Comment: @felwithe: It is if it will leave 90% of their profile behind.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams he didn't say what he was trying to backup or why. He said he wanted dot files but not directories.

Answer (score 2):

To zip up dot files in your home directory:

```
$ cd
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ".?*" -exec tar czfv dotfiles.tgz {} +
```

If you want to include directories:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name ".?*" -exec tar czfv dotfiles.tgz {} +
```

The `?` is optional in the first command, but not in the second, otherwise, `find` will include the `'.'` directory.

(inspiration taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83661/creating-archive-using-tar-including-all-dotfiles-but-excluding-all-subdirecto).)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in one go, but you can run your command and create a tar file, then use the `find` command to append the missing . directories.

Something like `$ find -type d -regex '\..+' -exec tar -r {} /media/bjackfly/bkup/bkup.gz \;`

I have not tested this command as I am sitting on a Windows machine and does not have access to a shell, but you should be able to do this using this command or a variance of it. I am not sure if this command will pick up the `.` and `..` directories to.

Cheers.

Comment: At least on cygwin it does pick up `/.`, so you might want to change that asterisk to a plus.

Comment: Thanks I ended up creating 2 separate files but I am going to try your way to just append.  
# back up other files exluding dot dir
tar -cvzf "$BACKUPDIR/$BKUPFILE" --exclude '.*'  --one-file-system "$SRCDIR"`
# back up other files exluding 
tar -cvzf "$BACKUPDIR/$BKUPFILE" --exclude '.*'  --one-file-system "$SRCDIR"

Comment: not showing as code in the comments but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Using find logical operators `-and` and `-or` to select all files and directories which do not begin with '.':

```
tar -cvzf /media/bjackfly/bkup/bkup.gz --one-file-system $(find /home/bjackfly -type f -or -type d -and -not -name '.*' )
```

**Edit**
slhck commented the above solution does not handle file names containing whitespace.
This is one solution, perhaps someone knows a more elegant technique?

```
find . -type f -or -type d -and -not -name '.*' >/tmp/tar.$$
tar -cvzf /media/bjackfly/bkup/bkup.gz --one-file-system /home/bjackfly -T /tmp/tar.$$
rm /tmp/tar.$$
```

Comment: This does not work if files have whitespace in their name.

Comment: The find seems to include the dot directories when running

Comment: It works for me here and now

Answer (score 0):

so the real trick here is to create a regular .tar file and then use a find piped into another tar using the -u option to add or update the .tar and then just zip it up afterwards. Thanks to Mogget who had the basic idea.

```
#!/bin/bash
BKUPDIR="/media/bjackfly/backupDisk/bkup"
BKUPFILE=$(/bin/date +"%Y%m%d").bkup
SRCDIR=/home/bjackfly


tar -cvf "$BKUPDIR/${BKUPFILE}.tar" --exclude '.*'  --one-file-system "$SRCDIR"
find $SRCDIR -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '.*'  ! \( -name .Xauthority.* \) | tar -uvf "$BKUPDIR/$BKUPFILE.tar" -T -
gzip "$BKUPDIR/$BKUPFILE.tar"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not that.
If you want backup all files in the flat directory structure without recursion, use:

```
tar cvf backupfile.tar -C /specify/dir --no-recursion '.*'
```

unfortunately this backup dotted files with dotted directories. good news is, directory contents will not be backed up.

Otherwise if file names does not have new line chars you can use:

```
cd /some/dir
find ./ -minlevel 1 -maxlevel 1 -type f -name '.*'|tar cvf backupfile.tar -T - --no-recursion
```

look for -T option. with argument '-' this get file list from his stdin. list is generated by find command.
This approach is more better because you are not limited by maxumum command length, like examples given by others, for example tar ....something $(find)  or  find ...| xargs ... tar ..something... {}     that put full file list as tar command args. this can overflow command size limit.

option --no-recursion is in this case only for security. this cause, when tar get some directory, tar doesn't step for this directory structure. it's very useful in conjunction with find.

In this approach you can run (as dry without backup making) command find and you will see what files it takes.

Comment: Note that you could use the options `-print0` on `find` and `--null` on `tar` to allow newlines in file names in the second command.

Answer (score 0):

1.
`find ./target-dir -type d -name '.?*' -prune -o -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion -cvzf backup.tar.gz -T -`

OR

2.
`find ./target-dir -type d -name '.?*' -prune -o -print0 -exec tar --null --no-recursion -cvzf backup.tar.gz -T {} +`